# Is there a way to set the name for calling tel number?

Tags: ios, xcode, call, default, tel

I use this code for call a number what user set in settings.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *telURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"stringKey"]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telURL]];
```

Can I set a default name for tel number? Like in this app, they set a coordinates:

[image]

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/emergency-call-anywhere/id416442703?mt=8&ls=1

Comment: App description: Your GPS position is displayed on the screen when calling (if automatic country detection is switched on). Tell where you are!